# Chaining jobs in Quartz

Tags: c#, .net, quartz

I want to chain two jobs in quartz. This is my `Program.cs` implementation in .NET 7:

```
        services.AddQuartz(q =>
        {
            q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();

            var workerFirst= "workerFirst";
            q.AddJob<WorkerFirst>(options => options.WithIdentity(workerFirst));
            q.AddTrigger(options => options
                .StartNow()
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                    .WithIntervalInHours(24)
                    .RepeatForever())
                .ForJob(workerFaceit)
                .WithIdentity(workerFirst+ "-trigger"));    
            
            var workerSecond = "workerSecond ";
            q.AddJob<WorkerSecond>(options => options.WithIdentity(workerSecond ));
            q.AddTrigger(options => options
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                    .WithIntervalInHours(24)
                    .RepeatForever())
                .ForJob(workerSecond )
                .WithIdentity(workerSecond + "-trigger"));    
        });
        services.AddQuartzHostedService(q => q.WaitForJobsToComplete = true);
```

I want to start `workerSecond` after `workerFirst` completion.

How to achive that in `Quartz` and `.NET 7`?

Comment: Have  the first trigger the second?

Comment: Perhaps https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/faq.html#how-do-i-chain-job-execution-or-how-do-i-create-a-workflow will be useful.